# What is max size of file to upload using jQuery-File-Upload, can i upload more than 5 gb of file size using jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, max-size

I have jQuery-File-Upload running on my server. Problem is that, last time i tried to upload 4gb file that fails to upload. How i can push the limits of max file size? I think under 2gb file uploads with no problem. Server is shared and php 32bit version is installed. and at server php.ini settings are:

```
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 10240M
post_max_size = 10240M
max_execution_time 120
max_input_time 60
```

please any one help me to solve this problem. i m searching to solve the problem from 2 days but no luck. and i don't want to go to java applet solution. it would be better if i can fix this problem using file chunking, html5 techniques etc. 
And if any of my friend have any experience of solving this kind of problem using jQuery-File-Upload, please share. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upload upto 5 GB,In your PHP Code add the following

```
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1);
```

If you do this, You can set others as well in your PHP code.